# Want to use python to create edge loops with z positions that match to the z positions of a series of vertices

Tags: modeling, python, screw-modifier

So I'm trying to create a very precise model of a rocket engine impeller. 
[image: The engine impeller]

I'm trying to make the mesh as clean as possible. I've created one of the blades and the center, and the number of steps I used in the screw modifier match up perfectly to the number of faces on the cylinder.

[image: What I have so far from the top]

[image: What I have so far from the side]

What I want to be able to do is to create a series of 66 edge loop cuts, where each edge loop's median position corresponds to the z position of one of the vertices in the following picture.

[image]

That way, after the loop cuts are created and positioned appropriately, I could just hit remove doubles and I'll have a clean mesh that I can subdivide smooth with little difficulty. Doing it manually is possible, but I would like to be able to do it with python. I'm a beginner with python though and don't really know where to start.

To be clear, I'm not asking to write the script for me! I'm just asking for some guidance.